# Angular buildOptimizer breaking bootstrap carousel transition effects

Tags: angular, angular7, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-animations

I'm working with Angular 7 and Bootstrap typeahead "^3.3.6" carousel (change the version is not an option.). When I include the option:
`buildOptimizer` in `angular.json` the Carousel Transition effect stops working
I already read this solution but I don't like it https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9231

Im looking for another better custom solution.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i='index'>
      <DIV>VIEW hardcoded</DIV>
    </ng-template>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this the answer you are referring to that you prefer not to use? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9231#issuecomment-364456979

Comment: yes @Igor it is

Comment: So both the loading of CDN, as well as moving the resources to /assets/ folder are not acceptable?

Comment: No, that’s why I’m looking for a better solution